# Making box for typing something to make reverse

Tags: javascript

That's what I write.
I tried to make an input box for write something inside of the box and reverse it.
It can be number or string. But I don't know how can I stick together and make it work.

```js
function revNumb(num) {
  num = num + " ";
  return num.split("").reverse().join("");
  `/*  Makes code write reverse*/`
}

function revNumb2() {
  document.getElementById('box1' + revNumb());
  `/*For inputs in html*/`
  document.getElementById('write');

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="box1" id="box1"> 
<!--Thats the input box for write -->
<button onclick="revNumb2()">Rev Numb 2</button>
<p id="write"></p>
```

Comment: Please mark and upvote the appropriate answer which is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should add reverse value in your write id like this..

```js
function revNumb(num) {
  return num.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function revNumb2() {
  boxval = document.getElementById('box1');
  revString = revNumb(boxval.value);
  writeVal = document.getElementById('write');
  writeVal.innerHTML = revString;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="box1" id="box1">
<button onclick="revNumb2()">Reverse</button>
<p id="write"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`revNumb` function reverses the string or number.
`revNumb2` function to read the text from input, reverse and display it on paragraph tag.

```js
function revNumb(num) {
  return num.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function revNumb2() {
  var boxEl = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var paraEl = document.getElementById('write');
  paraEl.innerHTML = revNumb(boxEl);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="box1" id="box1">
<!--Thats the input box for write -->
<button onclick="revNumb2()">Rev Numb 2</button>
<p id="write"></p>
```